# how to SelectSingleNode in to XmlDataSource?

Tags: c#, xml

In my code

```
  XmlNode xNode2 = doc2.SelectSingleNode("PageQuery/QueryReport[@id='" + 1 + "']/MainReport/OpenReport");
```

how to select all childnode in XmlDataSource?

Comment: You've asked 54 questions and only accepted 7% ???

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Maybe there is a "leecher" badge some day.

Comment: thai best question board or Chat board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `xNode2.SelectNodes("child::*")`?

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(XmlNode.InnerXml)

var xmlValuesPath = doc.Element(ParentNodeName).Element(ChildNodeName).Attribute(NameOftheTag which holds the Values Inside it);
```

And then you can easily assign it to any control like :

```
lblCompany.Text = doc.Element(ParentNodeName).Element(ChildNodeName).Attribute("Country").Value;
```